# Storing 2D array into a file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store this array: `NUMBERSS[r][c]` of `int` datatype into a file that the program would create and then have every value stored inside the file. I tried but it's giving me weird complications.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("NUMBERSS.txt"));    
// Read each row.    
for(int r=0;r<NUMBERSS.length;r++)  
    for(int c=0;c<NUMBERSS[r].length;c++){ 
        System.out.print(NUMBERSS[r][c] + "\t");  
        System.out.print("\n");  
        // For each number in the column, read a number    
        // and put it in the array    
        NUMBERSS[r][c] = scan.nextInt();  
        scan.nextLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please translate "weird complications" into English. We can't read minds I'm afraid. What problems in fact are you encountering?

Comment: heh, just paste us the piece of code where you have those complications.

Comment: See [`ObjectInputStream`][http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html]

Answer (score 3):

What you want is probably writing the contents of the array to a file and read it later.

### Saving to a File

Since an `array` is also an object, you can use the `ObjectOutputStream` to save it.

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("NUMBERS.DATA"));
int[][] NUMBERS;  // Populate it.
oos.writeObject(NUMBERS);
```

This saves the array to the file `NUMBERS.DATA`

### Reading from a File

Reading from the file is simple too.

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileReader("NUMBERS.DATA"));
int[][] NUMBERS = (int[][])ois.readObject();
```

This reads the array from the file.

Comment: @Jake223 The comment just says to modify the array with his values

Answer (score 1):

Saving to a File

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("NUMBERS.DATA"));
int[][] NUMBERS;  // Populate it.
oos.writeObject(NUMBERS);'
```

`ObjectOutputStream` doesn't have a constructor with a `FileWriter` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably `ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("NUMBERS.DATA"));` instead of `ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("NUMBERS.DATA"));`. So a bit modified version of the answer given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026805/sri-harsha-chilakapati would be:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("NUMBERS.DATA"));
int[][] NUMBERS = {{2, 3, 5}, {7, 11, 13}}; 
oos.writeObject(NUMBERS);
```